# Compiled Visual Basic Application gets Runtime Error 52 in Windows 8

Tags: vb6, runtime-error, windows-8.1

The application that I compiled via Visual Basic 6 can run on my Windows XP computer. But when I execute the same executable on my other computer that runs Windows 8, I always get **Runtime Error 52-Bad File name or number** as soon as I launch it. I can't run the program even if there is no "Shell command" in that program which leads to a "Bad file name" error.

I used "Package and Deployment wizard" for the packaging process.
And also I registered the needed DLL's on the Windows 8 PC manually via the `regsvr32` command line utility.

I also cleaned the whole registry via a registry cleaner (Wise Registry Cleaner). I used compatibility mode for Windows XP but nothing solved the problem.

Additional informations:

- XP Version - SP 2
- Windows 8 Version-8.1
- VB - VB 6.0

Comment: You should install VB6 runtime on Windows 8. Follow this guide: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pareshj/2013/07/16/visual-basic-6-on-windows-8/

Comment: How do I ask a good question? - Help Center - Stack Overflow
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: That's a runtime error relating to a file IO problem, what file IO does your application (or its dependencies) perform?  If you are unsure try using Process Monitor to look for failed file system requests.

Comment: Seems very likely a UAC related issue.  Welcome to 2006, you have a lot of catching up to do.  There is no reason to screw around trying to "install VB6 runtime" since the components are preinstalled and protected OS components, as they have been for a very long time.

Comment: This is the line that I get the runtime error.

`code`If Dir(C:/file.txt) = "" then
 MsgBox "Sorry ,Files are missing", vbOKOnly + vbInformation
end if
`code`

When this file does not exist I get this same runtime error.
In windows XP I am not getting any error,but in Windows 8 I am always getting the same runtime error at this line

Thanks

Comment: @Sachin: Do not add code in comments. You should edit your post by add 'formatted' code.

Comment: could you please edit your question and put in the code that you are using? ... Copy/paste the exact code that you are using now. Every ,"(). etc is important

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found the answer for the problem. That was not a problem in the coding; it was ALL about windows 8 compatibility. 
Go to the “Compatibility” tab of the properties window of the file and select “Windows XP SP2” under the “Compatibility mode”. That’s all

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your code is

```
If Dir("C:/file.txt") = "" Then...
```

Change it to a backslash ("\")

Comment: thanks for your answer. I tried it , but still I am getting the same runtime error

Comment: Add line numbers to your code so that you can determine EXACTLY what line is reporting the error.  I doubt that it's the line you think it is.  Also, show the complete code listing in your original post, prefereably after adding the line numbers and trying again.

Answer (score -1):

Windows 8 no longer allows you to write **programmatically** in the root of drive C:\ (and in many others 'system' folders like Program Files, Windows, System32, ...).

Try to use a sub-folder.

Comment: I edited path to "D:/Songs" as you said. But still I am getting the same error